# Remote wordpress database with variant local environments

Tags: php, database, wordpress, local, environment

We have one remote database, but multiple local environments which all have different unique domains eg:

localhost:8888,
localhost/work/domain.com

When working with Wordpress, we are looking to use a remote database however as shown above we have different local environments. How can we keep these in sync, without replacing the entire database every time someone makes a change? Due to this we can't use database sync plugins.

Currently the remote database carries through all of our local URL's and thus are incorrect when another person makes posts or pages.

Let me know if I can elaborate more.

Comment: Why would you replace a database when someone does a change (In the database? in the domain?)? Why can't you use database sync plugins? Do you have any error to show?

Comment: Say for example one of us makes an edit, eg: adds a page. The URL's would be saved into the database as localhost:8888?page_id=13, however on another's machine this URL should be localhost/work/domain.com?page_id=13, but this is not the case. The meta information is incorrect across the different environments.

Is there a way to avoid this?

There are no errors to show. Sync plugins seem to replace the whole database, overwriting others changes.

Comment: Without knowing how do you have configured the set up, it is hard to answer. I usually store the *content* of pages in a database, but the page itself doesn't need to be in the database, but I haven't managed a wordpress page at this level...